# What am I doing wrong with Threading?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

**Synopsis:**

I am trying to convert a non threaded application to a threaded application. I have not used threads in an application in about 10 years and am very rusty with the concept. There is just something I am not grasping. Can you please look at my (very short) before and after code to see what I am doing wrong and why it is wrong? All help is greatly appreciated! Thanks!

**Errors seen:**

My code is not responding. I can run and execute the buttons to launch the applications but rather than start a new thread and just work, they freeze and show a "not responding" message. I am not sure what i did wrong. Did i just implement the threads incorrectly?

**Non threaded code:**

```
//this opens the user input windows form
private void UserInputButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    enumerationStation EnumerationForm = new enumerationStation();
    EnumerationForm.Show();
    //userform UserForm = new userform();
    //UserForm.Show();
}

//this opens the correlationApplication windows form
private void CorrelationApplication_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CorrelationApplication CorrelationApplicationForm = new CorrelationApplication();
    CorrelationApplicationForm.Show();
}
```

**Broken threaded code:**

```
//this opens the user input windows form
private void UserInputButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BackgroundWorker bg = new BackgroundWorker();
    bg.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(enumerationStuff);
    bg.RunWorkerAsync();

}
//run enumeration application in new thread
private void enumerationStuff(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    enumerationStation EnumerationForm = new enumerationStation();
    EnumerationForm.Show();
}

//this opens the correlationApplication windows form
private void CorrelationApplication_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BackgroundWorker bg = new BackgroundWorker();
    bg.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(correlationStuff);
    bg.RunWorkerAsync();
}
//run correlation application in new thread
private void correlationStuff(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    CorrelationApplication CorrelationApplicationForm = new CorrelationApplication();
    CorrelationApplicationForm.Show();
}
```

Comment: Simple answer: Don't do that.  Use threads for expensive computations.  Use TPL.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's a bad idea to open new ui forms off the ui thread.

Comment: Also, seems like you are calling UI methods from the backgroundworker: `EnumerationForm.Show();'. this should pop up an exception for you. You should only use UI methods on the main thread and use other threads to do other-stuff-that-is-not-ui-related.

Comment: The reason I want to do this is to create a new thread for each application run. Every time a button is clicked an application is run. Does that not count as an expensive event? Thanks for the input!

Comment: Hummm, not sure what exactly you're calling 'an application'. But the wait you're doing will not work at all.

Comment: Why would you need to use threads for that? Just open a new form instance.

Comment: try to declare the workers as class members and make sure the forms you open don't try to reach the main form

Comment: You're not running applications when you click a button; you're opening a new window that runs in the same application. That would be the same whether you launched a new thread or not; new threads are still part of the same application.

Comment: Task or async programming on .NET should be on your way :)

Comment: @asawyer my concept is the create a new thread for each newly launched application. Each one of the those windows forms, is a application it is launching. I used this code as my most simple code example. Any suggestions on how to make the threads work?

Comment: @chris thank you for explaining that. I was unaware.

Comment: @toosweetnitemare simply put, don't do that. You can perhaps formulate an another question asking for something more specific for 'what you want achieve', because you don't have a problem, you're doing all the stuff in the wrong way. You need to start again :)

Comment: @toosweetnitemare I would suggest you go with the non-threaded code you posted, and see if that behaves the way you want. If it doesn't, we need to know what the actual problem is - what part of how the windows behave isn't what you want? In all likelihood I think the non-threaded code is actually fine.

Comment: @chris the non threaded code does work perfect. The only issue i have been getting sent from my users is that when they run the individual applications, they freeze up the whole application until the individual is done running. I would like to be able to have them run independently from this main console (what i thought would be a new thread for each application launched).

Comment: If the "individual applications" (which are really just forms) are freezing the entire application, they're probably doing an awful lot of work in the UI thread. In that case, BackgroundWorkers could be a solution, but you're using them in the wrong place. Find the code that's doing "lots of work" (whatever work that is), and see if you can put that code (and only that code) into a BackgroundWorker. What you can't do, though, is do anything with the UI from inside a BackgroundWorker - you only have one UI thread (the one you start in), and only that thread can touch the UI.

Comment: @chris can you put this in an "answer". I would like to give you credit for all of your help today. Thank you for explaining that to me!

Comment: @toosweetnitemare I already have an answer below, although I've now edited it to include some of the information from this discussion.

Comment: By the way +1 for a well written question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

BackgroundWorkers are designed for doing just that - working in the background. They aren't designed to display new windows or present any UI themselves - that by definition is foreground work. BackgroundWorkers don't handle any messages, so they won't respond to mouseclicks, keyboard input, or anything at all, which is why the windows just display "Not Responding".

It's difficult to answer this question since I'm not really clear on what you're actually trying to achieve here. What's wrong with your first, non-threaded code?

If the "individual applications" (which are really just forms) are freezing the entire application, they're probably doing an awful lot of work in the UI thread. In that case, BackgroundWorkers could be a solution, but you're using them in the wrong place. Find the code that's doing "lots of work" (whatever work that is), and see if you can put that code (and only that code) into a BackgroundWorker. What you can't do, though, is do anything with the UI from inside a BackgroundWorker - you only have one UI thread (the one you start in), and only that thread can touch the UI.

Comment: i was unaware of that. I've been reading background worker documentation for hours and that never occurred to me :) That could be my issue

Answer (score 2):

The .NET/Windows user interface does not allow performing **any** UI operation from anything from the **single** user interface thread. In a nutshell, the UI itself is single threaded, while any long running operations that don't touch the UI can happily occur in a secondary/background thread.

This is why things like `Control.Invoke` exist, to allow you to request a particular piece of code be executed in the UI thread context.

Comment: How would i make the control.invoke applicable in this situation? That sounds like what i am trying to do.

Comment: @toosweetnitemare That's what your trying to do but it's not what you *should* be doing. You would use `Control.Invoke` to *update* a UI from a background thread, not use it for accepting input etc. That sort of thing has to be done on the UI thread.

Comment: @toosweetnitemare: While what pete says is correct, still stick the approach Chris pointed out in his comment above. Apart from that: BackgroundWorker has a ReportProgress event, which allows you to update the UI with information from your worker thread, without crashing anything. But still this only makes sense in a scenario like the one Chris or James pointed out.

Comment: Yeah, Chris gives a more complete explanation of the proper way to do certain things in the background. Mine's more of the reason why what you originally tried didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

The main issue here is your trying to create & run GUI components on a background thread. Given you need to prompt the user for input I don't see why you would want to spawn this code off into separate threads.

Keep your form launching in the UI thread and then pass any extra work those forms do into a background thread instead.